# why is this volatile pointer convserion invalid

Tags: c++, volatile

Why does the assignment in the code below fail to compile?

```
struct foo
{
  int* m_NormalIntPointer;
  int* volatile m_IntPointerModifiedByManyThreads;


  void func()
  {
     //compiles fine
     void* pointerToNormalPointer = &m_NormalIntPointer;

     //does not compile
     void* volatile* pointerToPointerModifiedByManyThreads = &m_IntPointerModifiedByManyThreads;
  }
};
```

if m_IntPointerModifiedByManyThreads is a pointer to an int, and that pointer can be modified by other threads,  and "void* volatile*"  is a pointer to a pointer that can be modified by other threads,  why does the assignment require a cast, where the nonvolatile version does not?

Comment: volatile qualifier has nothing to do with threads, unless you're using nonstandard extensions of Visual Studio

Comment: @Cubbi: Or using IA64.

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
void* volatile* pointerToPointerModifiedByManyThreads = &m_IntPointerModifiedByManyThreads
```

It's a pointer to a `(void *)`.  Let's ignore the fact that it's volatile because it's irrelevant.  (Let's also ignore the fact that you're using `volatile` when you should be using atomics: `volatile` is **ALMOST NEVER USEFUL** for multithreaded programming.)

You can't convert a pointer to `(void *)` to a pointer to `(int *)` or vice versa.  Just like you can't convert between a pointer to `struct x` and a pointer to `struct y`, and you can't convert between a pointer to `(int *)` and a pointer to `struct x`.  None of these conversions are allowed.

```
struct x my_x;
struct y *my_yptr = &my_x; // not allowed

int *my_intptr;
void **my_voidptr = &my_intptr; // not allowed, for exact same reason
```

The only allowed conversions are between pointers to `void` and others.

```
int my_int;
void *my_voidptr = &my_int; // allowed
int *my_intptr = my_voidptr; // allowed
```

So if you want to do the conversion, you have to convert to `void *`, not `void **`.  Since `int **` is a pointer you can convert it to `void *` and back.

The following code is correct, but ugly:

```
int x = 3, y = 4;
int *my_intptr = &x;
void *my_intptr_ptr = &my_intptr;
*(int **) my_intptr_ptr = &y;
**(int **) my_intptr_ptr = 7;
// now y = 7, and my_intptr = &y
```